# PHP Soap - SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'checkConnectivityRequest' property

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm having a problem getting a particular SOAP call to work -most of them work fine, but this one is giving me a headache.

The WSDL is http://fibre.venus.ispwebhost.com/FibreClassTest/colt.wsdl, and the request I am generating is:

```
        $result = $soap->checkConnectivity(
        array('checkConnectivityRequest' =>
            array(
                'requestType' => 'SITE',
                'requestMode' => array(
                    'requestId' => date("Ymdhis"),
                    'siteAddress' => array(
                        'postalZipCode'     => $this->postcode,    
                        'connectivityType' => 'COLT FIBRE',
                        'bandwidth' => '2M',
                    ),


                )
            )
        )                  
        );
```

However I'm getting a SOAP error back (which I believe means it's not even passing it to the web service), so not sure if I'm mis-reading the WSDL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search in the content of http://fibre.venus.ispwebhost.com/FibreClassTest/colt.wsdl you will notice that there is not `wsdl:operation` named `checkConnectivityRequest`. The closest i saw was `checkConnectivity` so, try to replace `checkConnectivityRequest` with `checkConnectivity` and let me know.

Happy coding